# Intermittent "Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

Turning to the stackoverflow gurus as I need some help with understanding why this is happening intermittently and if there is a way to identify the root cause.

**TL;DR** I am seeing an intermittent (around 1% of requests) code 19 `NetworkError` for a `GET` request via a synchronous jQuery ajax call to an endpoint (ruled out as the root cause) and seems to only happen when loaded in Chrome/Firefox. I am trying to understand why this is happening and to see if there is anything I can do to confirm the cause or reproduce the problem at will.

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://differentdomain.com/api',
    data: null,
    dataType: 'text',
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        # This was added for troubleshooting
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "https://requestb.in/removed",
            data: {status, error},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Nitty-Gritty**

Unfortunately, our devs and our customers have not exactly been able to reproduce this problem ourselves.  The code that is being used by the customer's customers just report the problem to the console.  We are capturing the errors being reported in the console and that is how we know it's happening.

We have also used a third-party testing service that automate testing with browsers using WebDriver.  Their framework is reporting a `Socket closed` error but I believe this is a custom error they are reporting back and the request never actually gets sent out.

> Real network error or problem with the endpoint?

Initially, I thought this was genuinely cause by some kind of network problem to differentdomain.com but have ruled this out. I've run a python script that makes request to this endpoint about 20K times in three different regions. After around 200K total calls across several days, they have all (as expected) returned `200` status. This endpoint is also behind a pretty reliable CDN so I was pretty skeptical that the CDN was intermittently failing.  This also just seems to confirm this is only happening when loaded in the browser (Chrome/Firefox specifically).

The error function was added later so that I can have the client report the error to requestb.in for inspection and here is the relevant data being reported back, which isn't too much:

```
error[name]: NetworkError
status: error
error[code]: 19
error[message]: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://differentdomain.com/api'.
```

This is as much information that I could pull so if anyone has any suggestions on getting more data from this error, that would be very helpful as well.

After searching StackOverflow, it looks like when others report this issue, it has to do with one or both of the following:

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing

The `http://differentdomain.com/api` endpoint does return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and I believe this is all that is needed as this is a Simple CORS not Pre-flighted.  As a matter of fact, I do not see an `OPTION` request being sent unless I add a custom header to the AJAX request.  Is `Access-Control-Allow-Method` header needed here from the `/api` endpoint?

> Synchronous AJAX

I do understand using synchronous AJAX is bad practice and would completely accept it if this was the root cause but if it is, how could I go about understanding the case in which this fails?  Is there something I can look for to confirm this is the problem?

> Some kind of blocking extension

I can reproduce this error being reported if I block `differentdomain.com/api` using adblock on Chrome.  But we can reproduce this error using automated Chrome instances that we use for testing our app which does not run any extensions.

Thank you in advance if you can provide any advice!

Comment: Have you checked the network tab? Can you get us the request/response of the one that failed?

Comment: @MinusFour Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, we don't have access to that data; neither our devs or our customer that reported this problem have been able to reproduce the problem ourselves.

I was hoping that by using the error function for the ajax call, we could somehow get the information that may be showing in Chrome's network tab but it doesn't seem to have that information.

We have used an automated testing service that seems to be able to see this happening but it does not report the data in the network tab, it just reports that the remote server closed the socket?

Comment: Wondering if you ever solved this problem. This looks exactly like some intermittent behavior we're seeing too. Similar to you we are using synchronous AJAX. Would love to know if you have additional information.